# Pandas Сравнение нескольких столбцов

Tags: pandas, сравнение

В dataframe есть три столбца со значениями true или false.
Как удалить строки при условии наличия true именно во всех строках.
A  True True True
B  False True True

Т.е удалить A из df

Пишу с телефона sorry

Import pandas as pd 
d = {‘a’: pd.Series ( [True, False] ), index=[‘A’, ‘B’] ), ‘b’: pd.Series ( [True, True], index= [‘A’,’B’] ), ‘c’: pd.Series ([ True, True], index = [‘A’, ‘B’])}

Delete cell if True, True, True in all col

---

По логике, если есть False хоть в одном выбираем эту строку.

Answer (score 0):

Удалить всё же строки или колонки? Если колонки, то так. Наверное, можно оптимальнее, но сразу не соображу:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = pd.DataFrame({'a': pd.Series([True, False]), 'b': pd.Series([True, True]), 'c': pd.Series([True,True])})
```

DataFrame:

```
    a       b       c
0   True    True    True
1   False   True    True
```

Убираем колонки, где все значения True:

```
d.drop(columns=d.columns[d.all()]) # по умолчанию axis=0 у d.all
```

Вывод:

```
    a
0   True
1   False
```

Если наоборот строки нужно удалить, где все True, то так:

```
d.drop(index=d.index[d.all(axis=1)])
```

Вывод:

```
    a       b       c
1   False   True    True
```

Comment: Мой первый вопрос) Нужно, чтобы True были во всех столбцах, а удаляем строки)

Comment: @MASK Удаляем строки, где во всех столбцах True? Тогда вторая часть моего ответа подойдёт :)

Comment: Отлично спасибо!!!!